# Multiple CollectionView inside TableView Swift

Tags: swift

I have a Tableview, I have a collectionView in it. There is imageView inside the CollectionView. As you can see in the photo at the moment, two TableViews are created separately. But the data in the CollectionViews inside this tableView is the same. Important: I have one collectionView. CollectionView is created according to the tableView Count. The collectionView's hps has the same data. I want to upload different data to CollectionViews, how can I do this? There is a well-known tableView for circumcision and weddings, but the CollectionView contents are the same. I have to do it differently.

**For example,** I want to add the data in davetiyefilee Array to 1.CollectionView. 2.I want to add the data from davetiyefilee2 Array to the CollectionView

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47cKy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYjGu.png)

**UITableViewCell**

```
class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstColView: UICollectionView!
    var data = [String]()
    var collectionData = [[String]]()

}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  collectionData.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellDav1", for: indexPath) as! anaSayfaCell

        let rowValue = collectionData[indexPath.row]
        for i in 0..<rowValue.count {

           let deneme = collectionData[firstColView.tag][indexPath.item]
            let urlNew = URL(string: deneme)
            cell.denemeImage.sd_setImage(with: urlNew)
               }
        return cell
    }
    func setData(data: [String])
    {
        self.data = data
        self.firstColView.reloadData()
            }

    func setDataa(collectionData: [[String]])
    {
        self.collectionData = collectionData
        self.firstColView.reloadData()
            }
}
```

**MainView**

```
extension anaSayfaViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension anaSayfaViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return kategoriIsımYeni[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return kategoriIsımYeni.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
         cell.setData(data: davetiyefilee)
        cell.setDataa(collectionData: collectionData)
        return cell
    }

}

class anaSayfaViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

var collectionData = [[String]]()
  var davetiyefilee = [String]()
    var davetiyefilee2 = [String]()

  @objc func davetiyeCEK1(){

 if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
             for review in baslik {
               if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
                 let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                              self.davetiyefilee.append(s)
                               self.collectionData.append([s])
                DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableViewKategoriler.reloadData()  } } } }
 if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                                               for review in baslik {
                 if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
                 let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                  self.davetiyefile2.append(s)
                  self.collectionData.append([s])
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.tableViewKategoriler.reloadData()
                                                   } } } }}
```

Comment: i think you are doing something fundamentally wrong here. you shouldnt be nesting table views and collection views

Answer (score 0):

Swift has a handy property to its `Views` called tag. You can assign a unique tag to each of your `CollectionViews` and then add your data based on a condition like:

```
if collectionView.tag == 0 { 

   \\ your first collection view data assignment

} else if collectionView.tag == 1 { 

   \\ your second collection view data assignment
```

`collectionView` here refers to the parameter given by the collectionView functions above. You can assign tags using storyboard, but it is better to do that programmatically if you have many collectionViews. A good article that covers this: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Comment: Thank you. But there is one CollectionView. I want to automatically add CollectionViews by the program

Comment: The above article covers exactly that

Comment: I am currently adding two items and collectionView.tag = 1 always comes